# Algorithms for deleting multiple elements in arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to learn C and I am trying to write a piece of code which does the following:

1. Take user input of a natural number *n*
2. Take user input of *n* elements and store them in the array *x*
3. Delete all negative numbers from the array *x*
4. Print the new array, with the length *n* - *number of deleted elements*

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, count=0;
    double x[1000];
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%lg", &x[i]);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < 0)
        {
            count++;
            continue;
        };
        x[i-count]=x[i];
    };

    n -= count;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d: %g\n", i, x[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I have been told that I should replace my second for loop with the following code:

```
    int j=0
```

...

```
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < 0)
        {
            count++;
            continue;
        };
        if (i > j)
            x[j] = x[i];
        j++;
    };
```

Could someone please explain why is the latter code better?

Comment: Who told you that, and why did that person give you no reason for that choice? Personally I find both versions bad, because the `continue` statement could be avoided by simply placing the following instruction(s) into an `else` branch.

Comment: why cant you avoid adding -ve nos. into array in the first place?

Comment: If this is working code then the question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you really want it to be more efficient, I'd check for negative right after I scanned the number: `i = 0; while (i < n) { scanf("%lg", &x[i]); if (x[i] >= 0) i++ else n--; }`. The value of `n` is how many values (all non-negative) are in `x`. You're done. :)

Comment: @PaulR, thank you for your advice, I was not aware that there was part of stack exchange specialized for these kinds of problems.

Comment: And ... you forgot to control that `n <= 1000` ! Ready to write beyond the allocated array ?

Comment: @JensGustedt, could you please explain why is it better to use an `if...else` statement than a `continue` statement?

Comment: the scanf function returns a value that indicates how many of the parameters received a value.  This returned value should be checked to assure that the scanf was successful.

Comment: the scanf() inside the first loop will probably fail, because no handling of white space (like newlines) was included in the format parameter.  suggest: scanf(" %lg", &x[i]); (notice the leading space in the format statement.

Comment: the array values were read in using the "%lg" format converter, so the output should use the same format converter, not "%g"

Comment: code should always prompt the user, requesting the value to be entered, Otherwise, the user will be run the program, then stare at a blank screen and have no idea about what to do next.  For the prompt to read 'n' the prompt should include the valid range of possible input.  the prompt for the actual array values should include the current number of the input.  I.E. perhaps "input# xx: "

Comment: the suggested code avoids useless assignments I.E. array[x] = array[x]

Comment: @Nina, because as it is the `continue` is textually hidden inside the `if` clause. `if-else` visually structures the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i==j`, then you're assigning an element to itself: not *wrong*, but a (small) waste of effort.

If you really want to improve this, avoid putting the negative values in the array in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I have been looking for. I would like to avoid putting the negative values in the array, but the point of this exercise was to practice "deleting" elements from an array.

Just another question, would putting `if (count)` before `x[i-count]=x[i];` do the same thing (prevent assigning an element to itself), yet still be more memory efficient than introducing the variable `j`?

Comment: Sure, although you don't need both `count` and `j` in the second version, so memory-wise its a wash: `j` will be what `n` ends up being in the first version.